# Is `route.transitionTo` deprecated?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, deprecated

**2023 UPDATE**

route.transitionTo was deprecated in favor of using the router service. See the answer from Andrey below for links.

---

**Original POST and Answer**

Ember logs a warning that `transitionTo` has been deprecated in favor of `transitionToRoute`. However, ember currently has `route.transitionTo` and `controller.transitionTo`. Only `controller.transitionTo` has a deprecation notice on the API and in the source code.

Is the notice that `route.transitionTo` is deprecated a bug, or is the idiomatic method of transitioning changing to `this.controllerFor( routename ).transitionToRoute()`.

**ANSWER: NOT DEPRECATED**

Turned out I had a mixing using `this.transitionTo` that was supposed to be involved in route's only but was getting used in a controller, which made it harder to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `this.transitionTo` in a route has been deprecated.

See:

- [RFC](https://rfcs.emberjs.com/id/0674-deprecate-transition-methods-of-controller-and-route/)
- [Official deprecation notice](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x#toc_deprecate-router-events)

The modern alternative is:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class TodoRoute extends Route {
  @service router;

  beforeModel() {
    this.router.transitionTo('todo');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that there's a related issue:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/18683

And mind this RFC note:
https://rfcs.emberjs.com/id/0095-router-service/#query-parameter-semantics

Answer (score 4):

from a controller you should use `controller.transitionToRoute` (specifying that you want to transition a route) from a route you should use `route.transitionTo` and it makes sense that route is implied due to the context.

Comment: Right, that was always clear to me, but why do I get a deprecation notice when using route.transitionTo, is the notice just a bug?

Comment: Hmm, here it doesn't reproduce: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/53/edit

It does reproduce in my actual setup (I've searched the source code for any possible controller.transitionTo instances, there were none).

Comment: why don't you use a debug version of ember and set a breakpoint at the deprecation warning and find out who's calling it?

Comment: found it, I have a login mixin and it was getting used in a controller when typically it gets used in routes.

Comment: w00t, glad to hear you found it, Mixins are cool, but i've totally gotten caught out of my expected scope before as well

Answer (score 1):

`transitionTo` should only throw a warning in a `controller`, You're most probably using `transitionTo` in some controller somewhere.

From within routes:

```
this.transitionTo('someRoute');
```

From within controllers:

```
this.transtionToRoute('someRoute');
```

Source: (http://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/964)